# Div with an unspecified height CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a div with a background image, but I do not want to set it's height, because content will be added time by time, and I want it to be extended automatically. Basically, I want something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvLDo.jpg

The repeated part will be repeated vertically to create a higher div based on the content. I hope someone has a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: I would look in to using CSS3 which allows for multiple background images.  Refer to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

You can create three parts (top, bottom, content). Top and Bottom (no-repeat) and Content (repeat-y)

### HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.block {
    width: 947px;
}

.top {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122540013/img/unspecified-height/top.png) no-repeat;
    height: 60px; // set height for your image
}

.content {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122540013/img/unspecified-height/content.png) repeat-y;
    padding: 0 57px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122540013/img/unspecified-height/bottom.png) no-repeat;
    height: 60px; // set height for your image
}
```

### DEMO

http://dabblet.com/gist/5865448

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chrislondon/9-Patch-Image-for-Websites

Try this, it's a 9-Patch for web development. Don't know if this is helpful, just found it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 divs, one for the top (constant height = height of bottom image, background image = top part), one for the repeating part (height not specified, background = repeating image), and one for the bottom (constant height = height of bottom image, background image = bottom image)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have three elements one for each of the background types. Absolutely position the top and bottom background images into a div holding the repeating background and then add the text with the necessary padding.

html

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
  Random text that can be expanded
</div>
```

css

```
#content{
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
}

#top{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-image:url();
  width:100%;
  height:;
}

#bottom{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-image:url();
  width:100%;
  height:;
}
```

Another, way is to use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.  However, it lacks support in older browsers here is a list http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/.

The code would be similar except you wouldn't have to explicitly create a top and bottom element you could just do

```
#content::before{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-image:url();
  width:100%;
  height:;
}

#content::after{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-image:url();
  width:100%;
  height:;
}
```

Another solution that doesn't have full support yet, but is probably the most ideal is CSS3's multiple backgrounds. http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ has some examples and a list of the browsers that support it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following css to your div

```
#middleDiv{
     clear:both;
}
```

This, along with not setting the height, will allow it to auto extend depending on content inside the div.

You could also set a min-height so the structure of the page is not compromised when there is no content inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Z2XRh/

1) add 2 span inside div, in my demo, `#imgTop` (Green image: which is part of your background top with exact height) and `#imgBtm` (Red image: which is part of your background bottom with exact height).

2) give background repeat-y to your div with your middle prat that you want to repeat.

## HTML

```
<div id="yourDiv">
    <span id="imgTop"></span>
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    Repeated background<br />
    <span id="imgBtm"></span>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#yourDiv {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    background:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_LkTxPZXvwBc/S-0kbnkwiyI/AAAAAAAAC98/oSUDpqeHESc/s1600/3colfwnce.jpg') repeat-y left top;
}
#yourDiv #imgTop{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background:url('http://i25.photobucket.com/albums/c88/janica_/greenbg.gif') no-repeat left top;
}
#yourDiv #imgBtm{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:60px;
    background:url('http://www.profilebackgrounds.net/images/backgrounds/bg_searing.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could even draw it from CSS :
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HEFtk

`rgba()`, `border-radius`, ..